# Are there arbitrarily large arithmetic progressions of primes for some fixed progression width?

Tags: number-theory

Is there any positive integer $b$ so that for any positive integer $k$, there exists positive integer $a$ so that all $a + bn$ are prime for all $1 \leq n \leq k$? My guess is not, what's a proof?

Comment: This is related to the Green-Tao Theorem. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem

Comment: That theorem states that there are arbitrarily large arithmetic progressions of primes. However the step-size of the progression $b$ is not fixed. I'm asking whether there is any step-size $b$ that gives arbitrarily large arithmetic progressions of primes (all for the same step size $b$). I'm guessing the answer is no and hopefully it's pretty easy to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider $k=b+1$. Then no matter what $a$ is, the residue classes mod $k$ enumerated by $a+bn$ for $1 \le n \le k$ are precisely $a-1, a-2, \cdots, a-k$, one of which must be divisible by $k$.

Answer (score 2):

With a step size $b$ the best you can hope for is a progression with length corresponding to the smallest prime $p$ not a factor of $b$, and even then only if you *start* your progression at $p$. Otherwise $p-1$ is an upper bound (the one exception being $3, 5, 7$).

Proof: Any arithmetic progression of $p$ numbers with difference $b$ is going to contain one number divisible by $p$. If that number isn't $p$ itself, then it's not a prime.

As an example, step size $30$ (with $p = 7$) gives an immediate maximum of $7$ primes, since for any arithmetic progression of seven numbers with difference $30$, one of them is divisible by $7$, and therefore only prime if it *is* $7$. (However in this case it breaks down to length $6$ as $187$ is not prime).